# localhost not working - chrome extension in vs code

Tags: angularjs, typescript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

In vs code, I have created a `launch.json` file in an HTML angularjs project. I am not able to launch the project in my localhost. It keeps on saying as `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:8080/)`.

***Project Structure:-***

```
Project => .vscode => launch.json
        => app
        => scripts
        => styles
        => index.html
```

***launch.json:-***

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the contents in your `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: @YanYang Are you asking about the project structure? I have updated the post. Can you check it?

Comment: @YanYang What do you mean `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: There's a file named `hosts` in Linux/macOS. `cat /etc/hosts` may help to make sure whether `localhost` is a valid host name. I've run into such kind of problem but I'm not sure if it is your case.

Comment: @YanYang I am using Windows. Can you tell me how can i do it in Windows?

Comment: @YanYang Can you check this [image](https://postimg.org/image/kh7n2lqcn/) which i got in my `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Not exactly the answer but if you are just concerned about serving the local files in simple http server, you could try using npm module [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)

Comment: @AnkitMishra I need to run through vs code with `launch.json`

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue.

Changing my launch.json file to the following solved the issue (Chrome is my default browser):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where app.js was in my root folder of the workspace.

Here's what was the preivous launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the **launch.json** file inside the **.vs code** folder, delete the last three lines in the **configuration** (**name, url, webroot**).

**Before Editing launch.json file**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "sample1",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

}

**After Editing launch.json file**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
    }
]
```

}

If above the answer did not work just delete the **launch.json** file in the **.vs code** Folder.
both worked for me.

Comment: Thank you @Senthur Kumaran, This solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your setting put all in your launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 4200,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's not formated but once you copy and past in .json page and press ctr+k+D

Comment: Then it will be auto formate. And run ng serve or ng s --open

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the URL line? Here it is below:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
       // "url": "http://localhost:8080", remove this line?
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
] }
```

I also

1. Installed Node JS on my computer (Download link -- https://nodejs.org/)
2. On Visual Studio, enter (Ctrl + Shift + X) and search 'Live Server'
3. Install 'Live Server' by Ritwick Dey, close and reopen Visual Studio